# Anonymous access active, but getting access denied SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, anonymous-authentication

I have created a Site Collection, which I have granted anonymous access.

I have the home page, and other pages, such a resources..and they work with anonymous access, you can view the content.

Under the resources page, I have a link to another page in SharePoint, but when I enable anonymous access, the page contains web parts that say "Access Denied." When I log in, I am able to view the web parts.

One of the things that seems odd, is that when I log in an just modify a web part by just opening the modify and saving it, on my other browser, I refresh it and it allows the anonymous user to view the content.

Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a custom web part or OOTB?

Comment: Yes they are custom web parts in a web part page.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if Page Output Caching is configured incorrectly (i.e. authenticated users defined to use the Anonymous cache profile) as what it is doing is caching the last page request for 3 minutes.  The reason it works on the anonymous right after you edit the page is because the page was last rendered and cached by a logged in user so the subsequent anonymous request fetches that cached copy.  If you wait a few minutes and then reload the page from anonymous, it will error out as the anonymous user does not have permission to some underlying element.

To check this, go to Site Settings - Site Collection Settings - Site Collection Output Cache and check the `Debug Cache Information` box at the bottom and click OK.  Once you do that, it will write a comment to the bottom of the rendered page that shows when the content was generated.

Note that this will also happen if you have a middle tier appliance that does aggressive caching that does not take the user into account.

Comment: I do not have the Site Collection Settings, I only have "Site Collection Features," "Site Collection Audit Settings" and "Site Collection Policies". If I was able to do the Debug cache, will that get rid of my problem? Or will it only display when content was generated? Thanks.

Comment: All that setting does is show you when the content was generated which would make it easier to trace the problem.  It could also be browser cache as I have seen that behavior there too